# Server error 500 uploading imageFiled. Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new

**model.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profiles/images/', max_length=255)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'photo')
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsStaffOrTargetProfile]
```

If I try with:

```
curl -X PUT http://url -H 'Authorization: Token cffca5718f98bd1d80a3247be7b0bd51c2f28444' -H 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data' -F "photo=@/path/filename.jpg;type=image/jpeg" -F "owner=13"
```

I get Server Error (500). The problem is the imageFiled because the item is properly modified without image filed.
I have no problems only through the html form of DRF, why?

Please, can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks